# Vuetify Combobox add new item as object instead of string

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am building a new/edit item form using `Vuetify(v2.6.3)`. My form has multiple combobox's that pull their items from a backend API as objects. I would like to be able to add new items, which the combobox is able to do. However, when I add a new item it's added as a string. Is there a way to add that new item as an object instead?

I only need the new object to have a `name` key in order to send it to the API to be created

Desired `New` item from `v-combobox`:

```js
{
  name: 'New Item',
}
```

Simplified list of items returned from API and available as combobox choices:

```js
[
  { 
    id: 1, 
    name: 'Item 1', 
    createdAt: '2020-01-01', 
    updatedAt: '2020-01-01' 
  },
  { 
    id: 2, 
    name: 'Item 2', 
    createdAt: '2020-01-01', 
    updatedAt: '2020-01-01' 
  },
  { 
    id: 3, 
    name: 'Item 3', 
    createdAt: '2020-01-01', 
    updatedAt: '2020-01-01' 
  }
]
```

Here is a simplified version of my Form:

```html
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title>
      <span class="text-h5">Edit Item</span>
    </v-card-title>
    <v-card-text>
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col>
            <v-combobox
              v-model="item"
              :items="items"
              item-text="name"
              item-value="id"
              label="ComboBox"
              return-object
            ></v-combobox>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'TestForm',
  data() {
    return {
      item: null,
      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Item 1',
          createdAt: '2020-01-01',
          updatedAt: '2020-01-01',
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Item 2',
          createdAt: '2020-01-01',
          updatedAt: '2020-01-01',
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'Item 3',
          createdAt: '2020-01-01',
          updatedAt: '2020-01-01',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

In my method which sends the form to the API, I could check the value of each combobox and convert to an object if needed, but I am wondering if it's possible to handle it in the combobox component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VComboBox` doesn't seem to support that, but you could workaround it by using the [component's `change`-event](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-combobox/#events-change) to add a new object with the entry if needed:

1. Add a `change`-event handler (e.g., named `onChange`) on the `v-combobox`.
2. In `onChange()`, lookup the entry in `items` by `name` (i.e., corresponding to the `VComboBox`'s `item-text` prop).
3. If found, set `item` to the existing item.
4. Otherwise, create a new object with that entry, and set `item` to the newly created object. Note the new object's `id` (i.e., corresponding to `VComboBox`'s `item-value` prop) must be unique for `VComboBox` to create and track it.

```html
<v-combobox
  v-model="item"
  @change="onChange" 1️⃣
/>
```

```js
let nextId = 1

export default {
  ⋮
  methods: {
    addItem(name) {
      const newItem = {
        id: nextId++,
        name,
      }
      this.items.push(newItem)
      return newItem
    },
    1️⃣
    onChange(entry) {
      if (typeof entry === 'string' && entry.trim()) {
        2️⃣
        const item = this.items.find(item => item.name === entry)
        if (item) {
          3️⃣
          this.item = item
        } else {
          4️⃣
          this.item = this.addItem(entry)
        }
      }
    },
  },
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vuetify-vcombobox-with-object-on-input?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Answer (score 1):

I found the accepted answer useful but here is a similar solution that allows for a multiple selection combo box using chips.  I used this to implement a way for a user to select multiple "Tags":

Ex. [Stackblitz runnable example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vuetify-vcombobox-with-object-on-input-tvdvb7?file=src%2FApp.vue)

```
<v-combobox
 v-model="selectedItems"
 :items="items"
 chips
 clearable
 multiple
 @change="OnChange"
 item-text="TagName"
 item-value="TagId"
 label="Categories"
 solo
 prepend-icon="mdi-tag-multiple"
 return-object>
    <template v-slot:selection="{ attrs, item, select, selected }">
        <v-chip
            v-bind="attrs"
            :input-value="selected"
            color="primary"
            close
            @click="select"
            @click:close="RemoveTag(item)"
        >
          <span>{{ item.TagName }}</span>
        </v-chip>
    </template>
</v-combobox>
```

Here is the code that handles the Add/Removal of these tags:

```
private OnChange(tags: any) {
    let tagsArray = tags as [];

    tagsArray.forEach(function(tag: any) {
      // New tags are added as type "string" so we need to convert this to a Tag
      // Iterate through the selected Tags and for each "string" found convert it to a Tag
      if (typeof tag === 'string' && tag.trim()) {
        const item = this.selectedItems.find(item => item === tag);
        
        if (item) {
          let newTag = new Tag(0, tag);
          
          // Remove the string based tag
          const index = this.selectedItems.indexOf(tag, 0);
          if (index > -1) {
            this.selectedItems.splice(index, 1);
          }
          
          // Add a new tag object instead
          this.selectedItems.push(newTag);
          
          return;
        }
      }
    }.bind(this))
}
  
private RemoveTag(tagToRemove: Tag) {
    var indexOfItemToRemove = this.selectedItems.findIndex(x => x.TagName == tagToRemove.TagName);
    this.selectedItems.splice(indexOfItemToRemove, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear that a ComboBox can directly return an object when adding a new item. However it looks like you can leverage the `input` event of the component to run a method that converts to an object.

Here is how I call the method on the component's `input` event:

```html
<v-combobox
  v-model="item"
  :items="items"
  item-text="name"
  item-value="id"
  label="ComboBox"
  return-object
  @input="makeObject"
></v-combobox>
```

`@input="makeObject"` listens for the component's `input` event and calls the `makeObject` method and passes the currently selected item

Then I was able to write a method which checks if the combobox value is a string. If so then it converts it to an object

```html
<script>
export default {
  name: "TestForm",
  data() {
    return {
      item: null
      // Remaining code omitted for readability
    }
  }
  methods: {
    makeObject(val) {
      if (typeof val === "string") {
        this.item = {
          name: val,
        };
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Here is my full component:

```html
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title>
      <span class="text-h5">Edit Item</span>
    </v-card-title>
    <v-card-text>
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col>
            <v-combobox
              v-model="item"
              :items="items"
              item-text="name"
              item-value="id"
              label="ComboBox"
              return-object
              @input="makeObject"
            ></v-combobox>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-card-text>
    <v-card-text>
      {{ item }}
    </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "TestForm",
  data() {
    return {
      item: null,
      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Item 1",
          createdAt: "2020-01-01",
          updatedAt: "2020-01-01",
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Item 2",
          createdAt: "2020-01-01",
          updatedAt: "2020-01-01",
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Item 3",
          createdAt: "2020-01-01",
          updatedAt: "2020-01-01",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    makeObject(val) {
      if (typeof val === "string") {
        this.item = {
          name: val,
        };
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

[sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-williams-zybo3?file=/src/components/TestForm.vue:0-1279)